# MYSQL GROUP BY and SUM with clause

Tags: mysql

Hello there are two tables

**Interval**

| id | is_full |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |

**entry_penalty**

| interval_id | entry_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 14 | 55 |
| 3 | 14 | 7 |
| 3 | 14 | 1 |
| 1 | 15 | 4 |
| 1 | 15 | 8 |
| 2 | 15 | 11 |

So i am trying to display Sum of all **entry_penalties** per **interval**, twist is even if there is no relation between **entry_penalty** and **interval** table i should display full course interval sum per entry_id (related to **is_full** field).

For example total results should be in this case

| interval_id | entry_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14 | 63 |
| 2 | 14 | 55 |
| 3 | 14 | 8 |
| 1 | 15 | 23 |
| 2 | 15 | 11 |

I have tried with sub query but it ignores to do calculation when there is no relation between **entry_penalties** and **interval** tables regarding **is_full** column.
My code so far.

```
 SELECT 
      ep.interval_id,
       IF (
         i.is_full, 
           (
              SELECT SUM(ep2.amount) * 1000 FROM entry_penalty as ep2 
                WHERE ep2.entry_id = ep.entry_id
           ),
           SUM(ep.amount) * 1000
       ) as penalty_time, 
      ep.entry_id
      FROM entry_penalty ep
      INNER JOIN \`interval\` i ON i.id = ep.interval_id
      WHERE ep.entry_id IN (:entryIds)
      GROUP BY interval_id, entry_id`
```

Comment: For interval_id = 1, entry_id is 15 but your expected result it's 14 & 15. Any logic behind this.

Comment: @RahulBiswas yes so it is aggregate interval, it is always there even if there is not relation between tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose to deal with the two cases (full, not full) separately, and then use `union all` to combine the two results:

```
SELECT     i.id, ep.entry_id, SUM(ep.amount)
FROM       `interval` i, 
           entry_penalty ep
WHERE      i.is_full
GROUP BY   i.id, ep.entry_id
UNION ALL
SELECT     i.id, ep.entry_id, SUM(ep.amount)
FROM       entry_penalty ep
INNER JOIN `interval` i 
        ON ep.interval_id = i.id 
       AND NOT i.is_full
GROUP BY   i.id, ep.entry_id
ORDER BY   2, 1
```

See it run on [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a65df5b446584b601d178bb805924eb2), where it outputs:

| id | entry_id | SUM(ep.amount) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14 | 63 |
| 2 | 14 | 55 |
| 3 | 14 | 8 |
| 1 | 15 | 23 |
| 2 | 15 | 11 |

Comment: is there any chance to avoid UNION ALL and any faster solution?

Comment: Possibly, but all that depends on your actual data, volume of data, indexes,...etc. `UNION ALL` is not slow by itself. When the proper indexes are used it will be fast.

Comment: sorry, it was my fault i have one additional column race_id, so specific intervals are related to specific race, i had to add additional filter  WHERE i.race_id = :raceId, so that is why got unexpected results first place.

Comment: deleted, good job tnx once again.